# problem when creating a new connection in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

when I created a new connection I find that it contains same content as the previous one, even I have not written anything to this new connection.

Comment: Please share some more details.

Comment: @Ankit, for example, I would like to create a new table but I find in this connection that it already has a table for the previous connection.

Comment: What do you mean by new connection? A new user?

Comment: new DB connection

Comment: @DORRAAMRI - once you create a table it will continue to exist until you tell the database to delete it. You can do this using the `DROP TABLE` command.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL Developer connection is just a **session**. If you use the same **username** as an existing connection's user you will see the objects belonging to that schema.

If you want to create a new user [you actually have to create a new user](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503). Connect as SYS (using SYSDBA connection) and

```
create user new_user identified by some_password
default tablespace users;
grant create session, create table, create procedure to new_user;
grant quota 100M on users to new_user;
```

Obviously give the user an appropriate name for your needs. Grant it all the privileges it needs. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2077938).

Once you have created the user you can create a SQL Developer connection for it.

Comment: when I write the role is SYSDBA he showed me the username or password invalid.

Comment: Are you connecting as SYS? Did you set up this database? Or did someone else? Who is the DBA?

Comment: I connected as a username system I choose the default role and the SID xe. to create a new user, what should I do!

Comment: Were you able to connect as SYSTEM? If so, did you run the statement I posted in my answer?