# an error in sqldeveloper of Inconsistent Data Types

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to insert a line in my database. but he showed me this error.

> SQL error: ORA-00932: inconsistent data types; waited: SYSTEM.HYPOTHESES; got: SYSTEM.HYPOTHESIS 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected% s got% s

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it trying to do something like changing a varchar into a number or date type while expecting that it doesn't contain crap data? [ORA-00932](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00932.php)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: **NEVER** ever use the SYSTEM user to create your own object. Create a regular user, and use that. Do **not** use the SYS or SYSTEM users for your regular work.

Comment: how can I create a regular user without using the SYSTEM user??

Comment: *"how can I create a regular user without using the SYSTEM user??"* Well you could trying connecting as SYSTEM and running [the statements I posted in response to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230890/146325`)

Answer (score 1):

```
SYSTEM.HYPOTHESES
               -
```

is different from

```
SYSTEM.HYPOTHESIS 
               -
```

By the way, you'd rather not do what you are doing in `SYSTEM` schema.

Comment: Nice catch :)  So easy to overlook typos. +1